# Python IDLE won't launch - (Using MAC 10.8.5 /Python and UNIX noobie)

Tags: python, macports, homebrew

Months ago, I installed Python 2.7 on my MacBook Pro (OS 10.8.5) and was using IDLE to run programs for classes I was taking on Udacity. One morning IDLE would no longer start, it would just bounce around on the dock and then close. I was eventually able to get things working again by installing Python 3.3 and using that IDLE.

A few days ago, I tried to get 2.7 working again by uninstalling all versions of Python and reinstalling using Macports. (To uninstall, I simply deleted the Python folders in my application folder, the Python.framework file in /Library/Frameworks and some symlinks in /usr/local/bin.

Now no version of Python is working for me. When I try to start IDLE, I get the following error message in the Console:

2/7/14 10:28:02.556 PM com.apple.launchd.peruser.502[151]: ([0x0-0xc80c8].org.python.IDLE[819]) Exited with code: 1

The Python in the terminal still works, by the way. I also tried installing another IDE, PyCharm, but that doesn't work either (I get a message saying No Python interpreter selected).

I think I may have royally screwed things up by installing multiple package managers while first trying to get Python working on my machine: PIP, Homebrew, Macports. I did not realize at the time that these package managers would be so tricky to uninstall. Any tips on how to get everything working again would be deeply appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have too many packages installed through homebrew and macports you could try uninstalling them (presumably you installed pip through one of these?).

You can uninstall homebrew as per https://gist.github.com/mxcl/1173223, and macports as outlined http://guide.macports.org/#installing.macports.uninstalling.

Python from the terminal will still function, as python is an integral part of OSX and ships with the OS.

I've not used pycharm, but I suspect you need to select the interpreter in the preferences as described here http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/python-interpreters.html.

If you get really stuck, you could always install linux on your mac ;-)

Good luck.